# Chrome Extension Word Count: Selected Text Not Updating in Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I've been working on a Chrome extension that counts the number of words in selected text on a web page and displays the count in a popup. The popup is working and shows the initial word count, I'm encountering an issue where the word count remains at 0 when I select text on the page. I'm looking for a bit of help with this. Any insights, suggestions, or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Manifest File (manifest.json):

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Word Counter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Counts words in selected text and displays a pop-up.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab",
    "scripting"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
          },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["popup.js"]
      }
    ]
}
```

Popup HTML (popup.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Word Count Extension</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Word Count</h1>
  <p id="wordCount">0 words</p>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (popup.js):

```
console.log("Content script is running");

// Function to count words in the selected text
function countWords(selectedText) {
  const wordCount = selectedText.split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean).length;
  return wordCount;
}

// Handle the selection change event
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  const wordCount = countWords(selectedText);
  console.log("Selected Text: " + selectedText);
  console.log("Word Count: " + wordCount);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ wordCount: wordCount });
});

console.log("Popup script is running");

// Handle the message sent from the content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.wordCount !== undefined) {
    document.getElementById("wordCount").textContent =
      message.wordCount + " word(s)";
  }
});
```

I'll also mention that I'm getting the following two errors when I inspect the popup in Dev Tools:

- Error 1 (popup.js:28): Uncaught TypeError - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onSelectionChanged')"
- Error 2 (popup.html:1): Error handling response - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')

**Additional Information:**

- I've granted the "activeTab" permission in my manifest file to access the active tab.
- I've used "manifest_version": 3 as required for Chrome extension development.

Comment: 1) There's no such thing as chrome.scripting.onSelectionChanged. 2) Use `selectionchange` event in the content script and then chrome.runtime.sendMessage. 3) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for this! It's working a bit better now. I followed your advice and updated the code (see above), and added event listeners to the popup to test that it's working. It seems to only count the words inside the popup, rather than on the web page.

Comment: You need to use a [content script](/a/67227376).